# How to make margin collapsing work with input type=button/submit?

Tags: css, input, margin

Consider [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/8mqHZ/3/):

```
<p style="margin: 30px 0; padding: 0;">Some text some text some text some text some
text some text some text some text</p>

<p style="margin: 30px 0; padding: 0;">Some text some text some text some text some
text some text some text some text</p>

<input type="button" value="Button" style="margin: 30px 0; padding: 0; float: right;"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

`30px` margin expected between last `p` and `input` but there is `60px` margin. Apparently margin collapsing not working. How to fix CSS rules of `input` while keeping the ability of `input` to produce `30px` vertical margin on top?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting `display:block` on the `input`

EDIT: Just throw a wrapper around it then?

http://jsfiddle.net/8mqHZ/13/

Comment: Strange thing, in sample code it helps, in production it does not. Trying to isolate the cause...

Comment: Aha, isolated, the cause is `float: right` (code updated). How to keep it floating right and have no double margin?

Comment: @actual Well, margin collapse, if I remember correctly, doesn't apply for floated elements. It might be better to simply set the 30px on one side.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: the problem is that element on top of the button may have bottom margin of 0 and I can not control this.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found:

```
<div style="text-align: right; margin: 30px 0;">
    <input type="button" value="Button" />
</div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

A little bit of hack.